# Print 4 page forms (a4) size on A3 paper

Tags: pdfpages, paper-size, paper

I have a 4 page latex form on A4 paper. I want to print it on a3 paper (2 a4 pages=a3) so that page 1 and 4 can print on one side and 2-3 print on other side. 
How  can I do it?
Kindly help

Comment: Once you export your document to a pdf, it has very little to do with LaTeX anymore. It has more to do with your printer-software.

Comment: You can do that with `pdfpages`. First write the code for your document on A4 paper, then include it in the main document with option `a3paper`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. Do I have to upload pdf generated to overleaf to get pdfpages working ?

Comment: Yes. I'll post an example of the code of the main file, with some explanations.

Comment: See also [`pdfjam`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfjam). It allows to use `pdfpages` without explicit TeX file for the n-up formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of the code for a booklet I wrote a few years ago.  It was a booklet at the A5 format printed on A4 paper sheets (lanscape). The original document (a5paper) was 23 pages long, including the title page. In the booklet, I wanted the text to begin on an odd page, so I had to insert a blank page, and I wanted a blank sheet after the end of the text (which makes a total of 26 pages). As you print 4 A5 pages for each A4 paper sheet, you have to  set the *signature* to the `first multiple of 4` after the total number of pages – in the present case, `28`. So I used this short code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt, twoside]{book}%

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages = {1,{},2-23},signature=28,landscape]{4LittleChildrenA5.pdf}

\end{document}
```

*Added*: As @Schweinebacke pointed, we can use the `booklet` option to `\includepdf`, which makes the package calculate the signature in your place. In the example  I've given, you obtain the same result  with the code:

```
\includepdf[pages = {1,{},2-23,{}}, booklet,landscape]{4LittleChildrenA5.pdf}
```

Here is how the booklet begins and ends:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should use option `booklet` if you always want one signature for all pages. BTW: The OP wants A4 pages on A3 paper. Maybe you could adapt the example code.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I didn't forget the the O.P. wants A4 pages on A3 paper, but I preferred to explain what I really did. He/she will to to replace in the  code `a4paper` with `a3paper`, and to compile the original document as `a4paper` in the place of `a5paper`. As to the option `booklet` I didn't have to use it.

Comment: Without option `booklet` you always need to change the `signature` value, if the number of pages changes. If you use `booklet` instead of `signature` you don't need. `pdfpages` will do the job for you. Wouldn't that be better? And if you post an individual answer to the question instead of referring one of the various already existing, wouldn't it be better to answer the question instead of showing something that has to be adapted to answer the question?

Comment: I've just tested it, and added this code. I had to add a final blank page in `pages=` (which was included with `signature=28` instead of  `24`).